# Limit return values by different value in column

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a table with 20k rows; 
In first column, I got just 32 different values (can change every month); 
How to limit this return to get first 10 rows of each one of 32 values, as like an "sub limit" in my SELECT?

PS: in case I'll got 320 rows in my query

Comment: With Chaos Legion's answer in mind, I'm actually wondering if stored procedures are acceptable soluion? With them, this problem would be totally different pair of shoes.

Comment: OMG, @bgomes06, that's miles away from initial question :-). Quickly, remove it before people see it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Row_Number` which shall give you your desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT FirstCol, SecondCol, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FirstCol ORDER BY SecondCol) As RowNum FROM YourTable
) t
WHERE RowNum <= 10;
```

Comment: Splitting to find the issue, I wrote "SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() FROM mytable;" and got ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION db_numbers.ROW_NUMBER does not exist.
Had to do this to find why I got "SQL syntax error" with your code @Chaos.

Comment: OP is using MySQL. MySQL doesn't support `ROW_NUMBER()`